# Date Ordered Archive Page for single category?

Tags: customization, archives

The code below enables an archive of posts in date order. But I can't figure out how to change this so it only pulls one category of posts.

[Link](https://gist.github.com/tribalcafe/8952742)

Any help greatly appreciated

```
<?php

//* Template Name: Custom Archive

//* Remove standard post content output
remove_action( 'genesis_post_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'sk_page_archive_content' );
add_action( 'genesis_post_content', 'sk_page_archive_content' );
/**
 * This function outputs posts grouped by year and then by months in descending order.
 *
 */


function sk_page_archive_content() {

    global $post;

        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1') ;
        $year = '';
        $month = '';
        foreach($lastposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);

            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month && $month != ''){
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year && $year != ''){
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year){
                $year = get_the_time('Y');
                echo '<li><h2>' . $year . '</h2><ul class="monthly-archives">';
            }
            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month){
                $month = ucfirst(get_the_time('F'));
                echo '<li><h3>' . $month . '</h3><ul>';
            }

        ?>
            <li>
                <span class="the_date"><?php the_time('d') ?>:</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        <?php           
}

remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_close', 15 );

genesis();
```

Comment: Please wrap the external links.

Comment: Have a look at the parameters that goes with [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add the category to this line:

```
$lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&category=7');
```

Replacing 7 with whatever category ID you need to use.

Link to the WordPress Codex page [`get_posts()` - Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters).